# "INSERT INTO t(x) .. SELECT MAX(t.x) + 1 .." sometimes returns "DUPLICATE KEY"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Good evening,

I've a problem with a simple "INSERT" sql satement that i was assuming that it's "bomb safe" but sometimes i face the error "duplicate key".

Well, i'll give you a simple sql code

**-- instruction 1: table create**

```
CREATE TABLE tab_1 (
    code integer,
    field_1 integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (code)
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

**-- instruction2: the insert**

```
INSERT INTO tab_1 (code)
SELECT 
    (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(code), 0) + 1 FROM tab_1
    )
;
```

Well, the problem i'm facing is that "sometimes" without any (IMHO) reason, the instruction 2 returns "duplicate key" on the insert for the field "code".
Obviously happens randomly, and I cannot explain "why" it happens or "how" i can reproduce the problem at my desk.
The only solution that seems to work is to catch the error and retry the insert until it goes fine.

Ok, so "the solution is served", but the main problem is that this way to use the "insert into" is widely used in a HUGE application with A LOT of tables and rearrange all the code where the same operation is called (declined for different tables) is something i want avoid.

Thanks for the help

Comment: It could occur with *concurrent* non-serializable transactions. Imagine where both transactions obtain the same `MAX(CODE)`, having the same view of the original data, and try to insert the same value.. *poof*

Comment: That is, the problem is not an *arbitrary* "insert into"; rather, a *specific* "insert into" which can cause constraint violations without proper lock escalations (see transaction isolation levels). For a specific use-case, an insert-retry *may* be appropriate depending on the table access and desired semantics.

Comment: Alternatively, if code does not "need" to be a *dense* sequence, a `SERIAL` column type (a PgSQL feature) might be useful - http://www.neilconway.org/docs/sequences/

Comment: "*Is widely used in a HUGE application*" then you have a HUGE number of bugs. This approach is not only absolutely incorrect but it's also the least efficient one. You will have to bite the bullet and fix your code to use a proper sequence based ID generation.

Comment: @user2864740 same as the comment for _JoopEggen_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SERIAL](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/) instead, which is something like AUTOINCREMENT.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id SERIAL
);
```

Never take COUNT+1 as two users at the same time could get the same ID, or mixed-up ID (if you use that ID further).

For good order: in a programming language like java, after inserting (without the ID) you can use `getGeneratedKeys` to obtain the generated primary key.

Comment: With modern Postgres versions it's recommend to use `identity` columns: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would love if you could turn that in an answer, so I can delete mine. Feel free to copy text. _(No need to get points.)_

Comment: "_in a programming language like java, after inserting (without the ID) you can use getGeneratedKeys to obtain the generated primary key_" - in any programming language that supports DB connections you can simply use `insert/update ... returning *`

Comment: @Abelisto in java JDBC one call executeUpdate with an extra flag for insert/update, and which only returns an int update count. Then you can call `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`. That is a bit circumstantial; hence the mention. Ĝis revido.

Comment: @Abelisto, in fact i always use the instruction 2 with the "returning" clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately we're still using Postgresql v9.6 and the "identity" was introduced in PostgreSQL v10

Comment: @JoopEggen the problem with this solution is to alter every single table, every single instruction that use the same way to insert records as specified. It's a way, if there's non other way i can use it, but if there's a way that let me edit less code of this application, i would love it

Comment: @AttilioDM: there is no functional problem with `serial`. The identity columns just have the advantage that it's harder to eventually "forget" to use them correctly. But using a sequence (which both, serial and identity columns are using) is the only scalable and correct way to generate unique values

Comment: @AttilioDM I can understand the problem needing to change all tables; you would need a backup, and reinstall all. As your momentary solution COUNT+1 is not concurrency safe, you might think of a _stored procedure_  taking a next int from a SERIAL like table, something like `INSERT INTO T(id, ...) VALUES(nextId('T'), ...)` but personally I would do SERIAL.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is subject to a race condition. Two parallel processes running that code will both read the same maximum, but only one of them will succeed in entering the incremented value. In other words, the operating is not atomic.

For a truly atomic way to do what you want, either use a sequence (if you don't mind gaps, that is the best solution) or use a separate table with a single entry that you increment atomically with

```
UPDATE counter_table
SET c = c + 1
RETURNING c;
```

Another way would be to use the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level, but that would be no better than your code.

You can also simply use your code, but set a savepoint before the `INSERT`. In case of error, rollback to the savepoint, get the next a suitable number and retry.

Comment: Actually we're trying to figure out how many times this way of inserting records is used. Probably we'll pass the column's datatype to SERIAL and edit every SQL statement that work like the written post. Anyway, is there a way to force serialization of every sql statement (transaction or not)?

Comment: You cannot easily force serialization, but you can easily have serializ**able** transactions, which is logically equivalent, but has better concurrency.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a simple sequence is your best choice here.